# Preload polyfills before executing main code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load some polyfills only if the user needs them but I can't get the scripts to download and be executed in order causing errors.

Dependencies have the asynchronous attribute and the main code has the defer attribute although is located at the end of the body tag so much of the parsing is already done.

Is there any simple way of doing this without using a preloader?

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Google Analytics
    </script>
    <script>
      var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

      if (!self.fetch) {
        var fetchScript = document.createElement('script');
        fetchScript.src = '/js/fetch.min.js';
        fetchScript.async = 1;
        firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(fetchScript , firstScript);
      }

      if (!self.URLSearchParams) {
        var urlspScript = document.createElement('script');
        urlspScript.src = '/js/url-search-params.min.js';
        urlspScript.async = 1;
        firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(urlspScript , firstScript);
      }
    </script>
    <script defer src="/js/main.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: by definition asynchronous means orderless execution. If you want ordered execution, you must execute synchronously.

Comment: @cowbert both dependencies can be downloaded in any order as long as the main code is executed the last, which that's what I'm trying to do with the defer attribute. I tried it without using asynchronous on the dependencies but problem with the order persist, maybe due to the scripts being appended to the document.